# Rsyng doesn't run from cron, but manually

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

I have a simple script for backing up files from my server. It does the following:

- Joins the server with SSH
- Creates a MySQL dump file
- Tar some folders
- Exits
- Starts rsnapshot to download the folder where the tar.gz and sql file are located
- sshs back to the server just to clean up files
- Exits

On the top of my crontab I've given the following

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

However, the scripts sometimes starts, sometimes not. Also Rsnapshot sais for a few of my servers when running from cron:

```
/usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /backup/configs/myserver.com.conf daily: ERROR: /usr/bin/rsync returned 255 while processing user@myserver.com:/home/user/serverdump/
```

Do you have any idea for both the issues?

Comment: How do you authenticate?

Comment: The server is accessable only with SSH keypair, passowrd authentication is locked. Here is my line from crontab:
`00   10       *       *       *       . ~/.bash_profile; . ~/.bashrc; /backup/scripts/server.daily.sh`

Comment: Under which user do you run the cron line? How does it access your private key?

Comment: The user has the same name on both servers and the ssh key is remembered with an ssh-agent. I would like to highlight that about 40-50% of my servers act like this. Others work like a charm.

Comment: In the cron, you either don't have the `ssh-agent` or a way to unlock it, if the key is encrypted. It will probably be the problem. Running verbose log should give you more ideas.

Comment: It has the authentication. Because the script works until the part where rsync comes into play. So it can SSH into the server, and make the compressions, etc... but at Rsync, it failes.